# Useeffect not update after i select new item on Select option

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect, setstate

I changed option but useeffect not update input. Please guide me where i make mistake. First i use useEffect to setCurrency after that i use mapping for getCurrency to add it on Select option. onCitySelect i added it to setSelectedId when i change Select option. Lastly, i tried to get address with api but the problem is i need to change api/address?currency=${selectId.id}` i added selectedId.id but everytime i change option select it is not affect and update with useEffect. I tried different solution couldn't do it. How can i update useEffect eveytime option select change (selectId.id) ?

```
export default function Golum() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [getCurrency, setCurrency] = useState("");
  const [getAddress, setAddress] = useState("");

  const [selectCity, setSelectCity] = useState("");
  const [selectId, setSelectId] = useState({
    id: null,
    name: null,
    min_deposit_amount: null,
  });
  const [cityOptions, setCityOptions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectCity({ label: "Select City", value: null });
    setCityOptions({ selectableTokens });
  }, []);

  const onCitySelect = (e) => {
    if (e == null) {
      setSelectId({
        ...selectId,
        id: null,
        name: null,
        min_deposit_amount: null,
      });
    } else {
      setSelectId({
        ...selectId,
        id: e.value.id,
        name: e.value.name,
        min_deposit_amount: e.value.min_deposit_amount,
      });
    }
    setSelectCity(e);
  };

  const selectableTokens =
    getCurrency &&
    getCurrency.map((value, key) => {
      return {
        value: value,
        label: (
          <div>
            <img
              src={`https://central-1.amazonaws.com/assets/icons/icon-${value.id}.png`}
              height={20}
              className="mr-3"
              alt={key}
            />
            <span className="mr-3 text-uppercase">{value.id}</span>
            <span className="currency-name text-uppercase">
              <span>{value.name}</span>
            </span>
          </div>
        ),
      };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const api = new Api();
    let mounted = true;
    if (!localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN")) {
      router.push("/login");
    }
    if (mounted && localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN")) {
      api
        .getRequest(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}api/currencies`
        )
        .then((response) => {
          const data = response.data;
          dispatch(setUserData({ ...data }));
          setCurrency(data);
        });
    }
    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const api = new Api();
    let mounted = true;

    if (!localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN")) {
      router.push("/login");
    }
    if (mounted && localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN")) {
      api
        .getRequest(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}api/address?currency=${selectId.id}`
        )
        .then((response) => {
          const data = response.data;
          dispatch(setUserData({ ...data }));
          setAddress(data.address);
        })
        .catch((error) => {});
    }
    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, []);

  return (
                <div className="row mt-4">
                  <Select
                    isClearable
                    isSearchable
                    onChange={onCitySelect}
                    value={selectCity}
                    options={selectableTokens}
                    placeholder="Select Coin"
                    className="col-md-4 selectCurrencyDeposit"
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="row mt-4">
                  <div className="col-md-4">
                  <Form>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="Form.ControlTextarea">
                      <Form.Control className="addressInput" readOnly defaultValue={getAddress || "No Address"} />
                    </Form.Group>
                  </Form>
                  </div>
                </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of the `useEffect` hook is the dependency array. Here you need to specify all the values that can change over time. In case one of the values change, the `useEffect` hook re-runs.

Since you specified an empty dependency array, the hook only runs on the initial render of the component.

If you want the `useEffect` hook to re-run in case the `selectId.id` changes, specify it in the dependency array like this:

```
useEffect(() => { /* API call */ }, [selectId.id]);
```

Comment: Thank you it works. I tried with getCurrency instead of selectId.id ))

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accessing the e object wrong. e represents the click event and you should access the value with this line

```
e.target.value.id
e.target.value.value
```

Comment: Thank you for help. When i add target it gives error.